# make text input send multiple variables to PHP

Tags: php, input

My assignment is to make a text input send up to 16 variables to print vertically below, the names themselves organized horizontally with each other. I'm using a table to do so (printing each letter on a row), and putting those tables in cells in a row of a bigger table so that they are organized horizontally.

This code successfully prints one input, but it only handles one input. I have it set up to print more, I just need more inputs. I'm supposed to only use one input to do them all. I can't figure out how to do that.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body><br><br>
        <form action="question_2.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="$N">
            <button type="submit">Print</button>
        </form>
        <!-- a table for containing tables that are generated within cells in a single row -->
        <table name="teams_table"><tr>
            <?PHP
            // insert it into each input and then to be grabbed via a GET request
              $N = $_GET['$N'];

              // start without any filled "team" cells
              if ($N == null) {
                  return 0;
              } else {
                  // verticalize each team name into a table and insert it into a table cell
                  $name = verticalise($N);
                  echo "<td><table name=team_table>" . $N  . "</table></td>";
                    }
          // turn each string into a table of rows of chars
          function verticalise($N) {
            $char = "";
            for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($N); ++$a) {
               $char .= "<tr><td>" . $N[$a] . "</td></tr>";
            }
            return $char;
          }
          ?>
        </tr></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example input/output looks like:
[ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLhvx.png)

Help much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide example inputs and outputs?

Comment: attempt to send 16 inputs and then update your question with what you have tried, what's not working with expected output

Comment: i'll post a picture of examples

Comment: attempting to send more than one simply updates the page with a single input printed

Comment: i'll include that picture now, and the code for the table

Comment: What's `$_GET('$N')`? First off, you need to use `[]`, not `()` when getting query params. Also, before you updated the code, you had it correctly: `$_POST['name']` (since you're POSTing the form with the value as `name`). But after the update, the code makes no sense at all. Tbh, the question is pretty unclear either way. What do you mean by "send 16 variables" and "only use one input"? Either you use 16 inputs, or you need to enter all as one long string that you explode in the backend.

Comment: gah my bad, version control issue, copied and pasted from two different versions, i'll fix that

Comment: Magnus, okay that answers my question, I'm going to use a textarea

Answer (score 0):

you could try to have the user separate their information with a comma and then use PHPs built in explode function like so

$newArray = explode(",", $N) loop and echo each value or use a line break statement.